# How to redirect a binding in IIS 7.5 (Windows 2008 R2)?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, iis-7.5

I have a "Default Web Site" with different apps under it... I have setup a HOST (A) record for a DNS name "support.mydomain.com" which points to the IIS server.

[image]
In the IIS bindings, i have configured the new HOST (A) record binding, what I would like to do is redirect any requests going to support.mydomain.com to a folder under my "Default Web Site" wwwroot.

[image]

As shown in the pictures, I'd like to redirect anything going to support.mydomain.com to the Default Web Site > App > SI folder.

Right now, it shows the standard IIS7 "welcome" page which is at the root (Default Web Site).

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use IIS URL Rewrite module for this.
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module